# window.setinterval isn't working with my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

For some reason, I keep getting the following error: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". scripts.js:37. I have no clue what the issue is. I am trying to display time into the html page using window.setinterval and document.getElementById. Here are my files:

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "The REAL Motivation",
  "description": "This extension extension makes sure you are always motivated",
  "version": "1.0",

  "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "home.html"
    },
   "background":
    {
        "scripts": ["scripts.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [ "tabs" ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"


}
```

Home.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>I am a chrome extension</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#34495e">
<div id="bigdiv">
 <div class="login-card" id="dateform">
    <h1>Please Enter Your Birthday</h1><br>
  <form>
    <input type="date" name="user" id="hi">
    <input type="submit" id="age" name="submit" class="login login-submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  </div>
</div>


</body> 
</html>
```

Timer.html

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<h1 id="whatever"></h1>
</body>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>

</html>
```

Scripts.js

```
function getAge()
{
    var age = document.getElementById("hi").value;
    if(age.getTime()>0)
    {
        localStorage.setItem("userage", age);
    }
    console.log('hi')

}

function showTime()
{
    var personTime = new Date(localStorage.getItem("userage"));
    // console.log(personTime);
    var deathMonth = personTime.getMonth();
    var deathDay = personTime.getDay();
    var milliTime = personTime.getTime();
    // console.log("Milliseconds on birthday:" + milliTime);
    var bornYear = personTime.getFullYear();
    var deathYear = bornYear + 78;
    var deathDate = new Date(deathYear,deathMonth,deathDay);
    var deathDateMilli = deathDate.getTime();
    // console.log("Milliseconds Death: " + deathDateMilli);
    var today = new Date();
    var currentTime = today.getTime();
    var timeLeft = (deathDateMilli - today.getTime());


     console.log("Time Left: " + timeLeft);
    // console.log("Death Date: " + deathDate);
    // console.log("Death Year: " + deathYear);
    // console.log("Death Month:" + deathMonth)
    // console.log("Current time: " + currentTime)
        window.setInterval(displayTime(timeLeft), 1000);
}


function displayTime(time)
{
    var timer = document.getElementById("whatever");
    timer.innerHTML = time;
}


window.onload = function () {


    if(localStorage.getItem("userage") == null)  
    {
        if(window.location.pathname != "/home.html"){
          window.location = "home.html";    

        }
        document.getElementById("age").onclick = getAge;


    }
    else
    {
        if(window.location.pathname != "/timer.html"){
        window.location = "timer.html";
        }


    }

}
if(window.location.pathname == "/timer.html")
{
    showTime();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you mean this:

```
window.setInterval(function() {displayTime(timeLeft);}, 1000);
```

That passes a function reference.

Your original call invoked `displayTime` then passed its return value (`undefined`) to `window.setInterval`.

Comment: If that is the case, the error message `unsafe-eval` wouldn't show up.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - In a regular browser setting, yes.  But this is Chrome's extension system, where all bets are off.  Apparently the OP agrees as well.